# call shell-sourced function remotely by ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I have function that is sourced through the .bashrc file on remote host A. 
If i use "which" on remote host A , i`m getting function body as output.
I need to run it through ssh remotely from another host B.
Currently , all my tries are ending with "command not found error".
I already tried to pass to

```
ssh A  "source /home/user/.bashrc && function "
```

, this not help.
Also tried force ssh to assing pseudo-tty with -t key. SHELL on both hosts is bash. 
ssh localhost on host A  still keeps function status available.

Output :

```
[user@hostA ~]$ which status
status is a function
status ()
{
    dos -s $*
}


[user@hostB ~]$ ssh hostA " source  /home/user/deploy/bin/_bashrc && status all "
ls: : No such file or directory
bash: status: command not found
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Could you paste the relevant parts of the output from `ssh A set`? Namely if `function` is there, what's in the `SHELL`, etc. Also does the problem occur when you `ssh localhost` on A?

Comment: Works for me (tm). Try adding absolute path names to all command calls in the remote function, and then decide if your `PATH` is to blame. Secondly, start small: define a sourcable file containing the minimum definitions, eg a test function printing "This is the test function" or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't. To do that you need to copy the sourced file on the remote host and source it in there. Note, that your file may be sourcing in some other files as well… This is almost like running local program on the remote host.

Comment: Basically, your change doesn't change anything :) I mean, you want to run function, that is stored on one host (A) on the other (B).

Comment: Hm, i would rephrase that i want  to run function, stored on host (A) , on  host (A) from host (B) .  Is it not possible either?

Comment: The `ls: : No such file or directory` suggest that sourcing in didn't go all that well, try minimal file being sourced in.

Comment: To follow up with the @MichaelKrelin-hacker comment, you can often get messages like that one when the line-endings in `.bashrc` are Windows line-endings (<cr><lf>), but you're trying to run it on a Linux/Unix system. Might that be a factor here?

Comment: Thanks all. Was my mistake. Sourced final file with function itself, omitting this way export of one important dir.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get the remote end to properly load your file containing the function into the shell environment.

I found with bash that the following works...
Put your function into .bashrc on the remote:

```
foo_func()
{
    echo Hello World
}
```

Then on the local side:

`ssh user@remote bash -l -c foo_func`

The `bash -l` instructs bash to run as a login shell (sourcing startup files) and then the `-c` tells the shell to execute the string `foo_func`.